# How to fix a git repository with lots of dangling objects, that fails git gc --prune=now with fatal: bad object:

Tags: git

I have a repository whose remote is on bitbucket. At certain point I pushed a branch to server, and by mistake asked to push all local tags.

The action failed after some time with an error (cannot recall exactly - but I think I was not allowed to change tags on the server).

However - since then I have these problems.

1. lots (~130) of dangling blobs, commits and tags
2. Any attempt to rid of these "dangling" objects - fails with lots of errors, all pointing to one specific "bad object"

   ```
    mini-mac7:myRepo $ git fsck
    Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
    Checking objects: 100% (16253/16253), done.
    broken link from  commit c521a9214898aac031831d97e6a8329342b788c4
                  to  commit a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
    broken link from  commit 19f55b6374e7adcc42046821c1659bb47df933a8
                  to  commit 0d862ff1507038edf4c26129abcc11ce8c00bef3
    dangling blob ab0129187ed300114d5d34501add4dc05feaeee0
    dangling commit 5a04331eb72123423888a4fac9922355588f138f
    dangling commit 350da8fc761b2b41d923ccad97cf77e320b0cf34
    dangling commit 8c0e4e66c891f4bffc23c1ee35f4d5eaca2bdb78
    dangling tag 9611c319d012589ea451ce56495f4c9673292615
    .
    . (130 more dangling objects... blobs commits and tags)
    .
    mini-mac7:myRepo $
   ```

and

```
mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent-broken $ git gc
error: Could not read a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
error: Could not read a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
error: Could not read a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
.
. (40 more times - same object)
.
error: Could not read a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
fatal: bad object a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
fatal: failed to run repack
mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent-broken $
```

Can anyone please help me revive this repo? First off --- how to fix the 'bad object' issue?  I already tried `fetching --all` from remote, `deleting .git/objects/96/11c319d012589ea451ce56495f4c9673292615` directly (only few actually existed, but when rm'ed --- the dangling objects did not disappear.

This repo is important - I already cloned it anew from server, but lots of local stashes and branches there contain work that I need. any attempt to pull/fetch etc. fails with strange errors because of these bad and dangling objects.

Answer (score 2):

A few background points:

1. The failure to push has no relationship to the local problem (whatever the local problem really is).
2. Dangling commits and blobs are normal.  The actual problem lies elsewhere (note that actual problems can cause "extra" dangling commits and/or blobs though, so one would not want to just discard all such danglers here: this means *don't run `git gc` on this repository*, although in your case fortunately `git gc` failed and *probably* did nothing).

Now, the actual problem begins—and perhaps ends—here:

> ```
> error: Could not read a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
> ```

From the `git fsck` output, we know that `a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3` is, or at least was, a commit, before it got damaged:

> ```
>  broken link from  commit c521a9214898aac031831d97e6a8329342b788c4
>                to  commit a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
> ```

Commit `c521a9214898aac031831d97e6a8329342b788c4` itself is OK, but it refers to commit `a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3` by hash ID, and object `a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3` is missing or corrupt.

We also see:

> ```
>  broken link from  commit 19f55b6374e7adcc42046821c1659bb47df933a8
>                to  commit 0d862ff1507038edf4c26129abcc11ce8c00bef3
> ```

which suggests that object `0d862ff1507038edf4c26129abcc11ce8c00bef3` is missing as well (perhaps `git repack` as run by `git gc` never gets as far as trying to read it so that it does not show up in the `git gc` output).

> This repo is important - I already cloned it anew from server, but lots of local stashes and branches there contain work that I need.

If commit objects `a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3` and `0d862ff1507038edf4c26129abcc11ce8c00bef3` are available in the fresh clone, you can install those objects into the broken clone and see if that makes it work.  I have had success with this technique myself in the past.  Jump down to the "copying missing objects" section for details.

If those commit objects *aren't* available, about the best you can probably do is run `git fsck --lost-found` in the bad repository.  This will, for each of the various danglers that Git finds (commits and files that aren't accessible through normal means), write those commits/files into `.git/lost-found/`.  The bad part about this is that *these files lose their names*.  You'll find the files' contents in `.git/lost-found/other/<hash-name>` (for each hash name); it will be your job to figure out what that file's "useful name" is.

(The files' names may, or may not, be find-able through *tree* objects, but `git fsck` doesn't save those tree objects anywhere.)

It's also a very good idea to figure out how the repository got damaged in the first place.  The usual case is a power failure or system crash.  Other, more alarming cases include disk / SSD failures: if you're getting these, it may be time for new hardware.

#### Copying missing objects

First, we'll test to see if some object exists in some clone.  In my case I'll use `ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb`, which I expect to find as a commit:

```
$ git -C path/to/clone cat-file -t ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb
commit
```

If this object exists as a *loose object* we can just copy it directly to the target Git:

```
$ cp path/to/clone/.git/objects/eb/f3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb path/to/original/.git/objects/eb/f3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb
```

(using the usual trick that the first two characters of the hash ID become a directory name, and the rest a file within that directory).

In this particular repository, that doesn't work, as `ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb` is only in some pack file.  There is probably some more clever way to unpack just the one object, but instead of doing that, this is what I would try: `git cat-file -p` turns the object into a "human readable" copy, and `git hash-object -t <type> -w --stdin` will turn a human-readable object into a loose object in the `.git/objects/` directory and report its ID.  So:

```
$ git -C path/to/good-clone cat-file -p ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb | git -C path/to/bad-clone hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb
```

Having transferred a commit, you might now find a bunch of `tree` and/or `blob` objects to be missing, and of course possibly more commits; this process can be repeated, somewhat painfully, one at a time.

There's probably also a simple brute-force method: dump the right pack file(s) into place and run `git index-pack`, or dump the pack file(s) and index file(s) into place.  That's not what I did in the past during one of these kinds of recoveries, though.  (I was lucky, I had clobbered just two or three objects and all were loose in the other repo.  I had run a bad `find ... -remove`, failing to skip over the `.git` directory.)

Comment: First off --- I re-claim, and can prove and reproduce the problem of the dangling objects is caused by the failed "push". If I create a new branch with single commit on a new clean clone from server, (branch from master) then attempt again to push - also pushing tags --- I get again errors, and afterwards I have dangling objects. Probably the "bad object" is a different matter (my Mac suffered many kernel panics because of some vicious IT tool installed by my employers).

Comment: Next --- THANK YOU A LOT for explaining this, but you didn't say HOW can I find and install the missing "commit objects" from the new clone to the corrupt one -- how to apply this technique? I confirm that I can see these commits in the fresh clone.

Comment: Try the same thing *before* the push; you'll have the same dangling objects. These are normal! (Every rebase tends to create some, for instance.) But yes, I forgot to put in the object-extract-and-install trick. I was lucky in my last case, I didn't have to use any fancy techniques, but I'll include some that should work if you're not so lucky.

Comment: Which "thing" ? After my commit - all is well. git fsck finds nothing, and git gc does nothing at all. Only attempting to push the tags causes this to happen.

Comment: Now --- how and where to 'install' the lost commit-objects? and where do I find them in the new clone, so I can copy them from there? Are they just files?

Comment: The "thing" here is `git fsck`: running `git fsck` in any Git repository where you've been working for a while tends to find lots of danglers. For instance in my mostly-readonly Git repository for Git (I haven't touched it in a while and actual development happened in a VM running Linux), I have one dangling commit and 2 dangling blobs right now.

Comment: $ git -C path/to/clone cat-file -t a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
commit --- yields an error and help - like the command is incorrect. If I remove the 'commit' argument,  I get 'fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info'. ls .git/objects/a2/df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3 finds nothing (.git/objects/a2/ directory exists). git checkout a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3 fails (fatal: reference is not a tree) but in the SourceTree UI I can "Jump" to that commit - see it, and check-out the commit without a problem!

Comment: regarding 'git fsck' - before push + tags --- it finds nothing - clone is clear, after the push fails (there are lots of messages there regarding all kinds of 'hooks' probably bitbucket things) - same 'git fsck' has 2 dangling blobs. but I do understand dangling objects aren't real 'corruption' and the repo is usable with them. I like to focus on attempting to clear the bad object error

Comment: Ah, then your pre-push hook is creating dummy objects and/or commits. (Why it's doing that is a bit of a mystery.) Anyway, back to `git cat-file -t`: the `commit` part above is the output from `git cat-file -t`, telling us that the object exists and has type "commit". If the object does not exist we'll get an error (`could not get object info`) => commit does not exist in the repository. So it's extremely odd that some GUI can see it (!).

Comment: It also occurs to me that if you have a bad existing pack file object at `a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3`, it may be that `git hash-object -w` will refuse to replace it. I can't test that without having a bad object file though. Not sure how to handle that - maybe explode the pack with `git unpack-objects`? I have never tried this, but it has `-r` and `--strict` options to help with recovery. (If I were doing this I'd experiment on a copy of the bad clone.)

Comment: I can simply duplicate the whole repo and play with a copy... but what's git unpack-objects, and what does git hash-object -w do? git is complicated and you really need to study its inner makings in Times like this, but I never manage to "get it".

Comment: I duplicated the repo directory. here are the first few lines of git reflog inside the duplicate: mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent copy $ git reflog
a2df338e (HEAD, tag: 1.2.1.202) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to a2df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
bb5d2e30 (tag: 1.2.1.261, master) HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
a152f482 (tag: 1.2.1.255) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from bugfix/ITMPROJ-1832-thfis-poc to master

Comment: I ran mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent copy $ git unpack-objects < .git/objects/pack/pack-a318c35b627e5a634fbcf1cc3761285130c868fb.pack
Unpacking objects: 100% (16835/16835), 55.61 MiB | 141.30 MiB/s, done.
which succeeded as you can see. That was the only .pack file in the .git/objects/pack directory.

Comment: After that: mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent copy $ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (16835/16835), done.

Comment: but still, mini-mac7:itx-mac-agent copy $ ls -la .git/objects/a2/df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3
ls: .git/objects/a2/df338e00be26da2f0b84543668ef29b52df5c3: No such file or directory
 As you can see above - my detached HEAD is not on that commit exactly, so I just cannot understand anything. Also, there's no .git/objects/a2 directory in existence at all. This is after running git -unpack-objects

Comment: Maybe I need to restate my need. I DO NOT NEED the dangling commits blobs and tags. I wish to remove them. Only git gc --prune=now fails because of the bad objects. any technique that will lose me these danglers and fix the bad object - is good for me. All I need to do is to resurrect my lost local branches and stashes that never went to the server. That's all. If I could save them as .patch files and apply them later onto my new clone - that's fine with me. Only currently the old repo is broken (bad object) and I can do very little.

Comment: Aha, I was assuming that the dangling commits might be crucial. If not, you may be able to use `git replace` to have Git sidestep the bad commit(s) entirely. Meanwhile, re the reflog showing ` a2df338e...` as the `HEAD` commit (via tag 1.2.1.202): you might be able to just force `HEAD` to start elsewhere. Apparently what happened is that the object itself got deleted (by whatever glitch corrupted the repository), but `HEAD` was left pointing to it. (BTW I had gone to bed, am up now but not at keyboard all the time...)

Comment: You got it mixed... we were discussing the ability to resurrect the "bad" or "missing" objects from the new clone from server. You said if the object exists in the healthy repo - I could install it in the corrupt repo. I tried to locate the object in the healthy clone. I could NOT find it (either as a file in the .git/objects/a2/... or using the command 'git -C path/to/clone cat-file -t' . To prove it exists - I simply checked out that commit in the healthy clone. That's why the HEAD is there. This is NOT in the broken repo.

Comment: In the broken repo - I don't mind losing any dangling tags (they all come from the server) I'm convinced that dangling commits and blobs are the result of failing push commands (as explained) and so I don't mind losing them too. What I do want to resurrect are stashes and commits in local branches not pushed to server. These I know by name - only I don't know how to go about in broken repo with bad objects

Comment: I don't know what git replace does. I'll try to read about git replace, but from my 12 years experience - I just can't understand git terms and how it works internally. Just don't get it. It's not for humans, not even for software engineers. I got to think like one specific linux geek (Linus) to understand it.

Comment: You can think of `git replace` as a translation lookaside trick. Just before Git goes to access some internal database object, having figured out its hash ID as `hhhhh...`, Git checks to see if `refs/replace/hhhhh...` exists. If it *does* exist, it needs to contain some *other* hash ID, `hxxxx...`. Git then tries to access *that* object instead. (I think this is limited to one level of replacement, otherwise Git needs to look for replacement loops, e.g., if `hxxxx...` goes back to `hhhhh...`.) But: if you can *check out* commit `a2df338e...`, it must *exist* as a commit:

Comment: `git cat-file -t a2df338e` should therefore show `commit`. (The `-C` trick is just to be able to do this in some other Git repository, in place of `(cd path/to/repo; git ...)`.)